# Data Synchronisation between new and old database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, architecture

I am responsible for synchronisation of data from a new system to an old system. I am using ssis 2012 and wondering what is the best solution . I need to do this data synch for new records, changed records and deleted records in the new system. The data synch is one way and needs to be close to real time as possible with ssis. Should I use CDC on the new database  or a message table from the source application to tell me the type of changes being made then use a stored procedures or ssis with separate staging tables?

I need to keep this process running for a year. Additionally the source and destination structures will be different so I anticipate lots of lookups, mappings and transformations in these packages.

Comment: Are the two databases on different servers? How long do you have to keep them synched for? Is it the whole schema or just some tables? Are the structures similar or do you have lots of lookups to convert data?

Comment: Yes on different servers. I need to kept them synced for a year. Table structures  different so lots of lookups, mappings  and transformations.

Comment: So you will be doing this for 3 years! What sort of change volume have you got?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of rows, going to millions maybe in a year.

Comment: A naïve solution woud be to record a log of all transactions successfully committed locally. When the client comes back online those are sequentially executed against the centralized DB. While this would "work", you also need to take in account concurrency and transactions that may have successfully committed locally may not successfully commit remotely. Therefore, you also need a way to undo local transactions. Not only that, but users must be aware of the distributed system nature because their scripts must take concurrency into account properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things to consider from my experience.

- if you don't have them already add a last changed datetime column to **every** table. Ensure that it automatically defaults to getdate(). This trigger can also capture the deletes into a local table for periodic transfer to destination staging table. *(If this is not possible can you have a "local" table that has the data from the last X months and compare with it to detect changes? Perhaps store the primary key and a checksum that you can compare with checksum from live)*
- create all of your lookup conversion tables on the old database or in a separate database, so that one day you can turn it all off. On the new server consider a separate db to hold your *import staging tables and the stored procures that do the actual imports*
- consider upgrading the old database to get better performance of capabilities - or leave it old and slow so that you **have** to retire it!
- I don't know CDC so I can't advise, but I have done this the hard way several times so I have scars and each time learned from the previous.
- I would have a table to hold your last sync time in a row for each table. You then can create a view or query that needs to be copied to your staging tables
- In your staging db, create  sprocs that will do each table's merge
- hopefully you have delete flags on the tables or if can get messy. You may need triggers to copy this data before it goes. You could then flag it in your staging tables
- build the extract system and schedule of with an appropriate frequency. Record metadata so that you can easily report on it
- build a separate import system with reporting. This side can be tricky to get the dependanciess in the correct order. *use SSIS to control the order of when tables are imported, but you might find it easier to develop and test if the actual imports are done by stored procedures in your import database*
- consider keeping the staging database data but use time stamp to show when imported/updated/deleted changes are applied (as well as the datetime of the change in the source system) in case there are issues

  - you say that this is a one way interface. I agree that is what you should say publicly now. However, towards the end of this project, it may be beneficial to reverse the interface, so that the old system is populated by the new (for either code tables so that they stay in line, or some of the transactional data).
- In other cases you may need to round trip from Old to New and back to Old or N > O > N, so that you can get the primary key data from both systems available for other extracts
- is the destination database still being developed? If so involve the developers in your plans, and the users!
- make sure your users have signed off on all of the code tables that they will use to classify data in the application. Ensure that they understand how you will map old to new codes. This may mean that where the is more than one new code from an old code, they will have to update these manually, luckily you kept the metadata so they can have a daily report so they know what to check!

Good luck

Comment: Cdc is change data capture . Introduced in sql server 2008.

Comment: Really good tips as the source system tables have no last updated date on every table, and I need to work out multiple status changes for some tables and not just last status change for a record .

Comment: You may be able to have several separate export and import systems some every X minutes, others just daily or after month end, as long as you know what is important when. You can miss individual changes as long as the system is faithful after an update

Comment: I think I will keep editing the answer for a few days as I think of more! StackOverflow Community I don't mind you editing it too if I have missed something!

Comment: Feel free to keep adding Mike.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest, easiest, way is to use transactional replication. It's not hard to set up and if it's very high volume you can use an old machine as a publisher so there is minimum impact on the servers.

Comment: For my edification, does replication address their need from the comments of `Table structures different so lots of lookups, mappings and transformations`